# How to convert a string to integer list in ocaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, caml, ml

I need to pass two list as command line arguments in ocaml.
I used the following code to access it in the program.

```
let list1=Sys.argv.(1);;
let list2=Sys.argv.(2);;
```

I need to have the list1 and list2 as list of integers.
I am getting the error

> This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
>            int list

while processing. 
How can I convert that arguments to a list of integers.
The arguments are passed in this format [1;2;3;4] [1;5;6;7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sys.argv.(n)` will always be a string. You need to parse the string into a list of integers. You could try something like this:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# #load "str.cma";;
# List.map int_of_string (Str.split (Str.regexp "[^0-9]+") "[1;5;6;7]");;
- : int list = [1; 5; 6; 7]
```

Of course this doesn't check the input for correct form. It just pulls out sequences of digits by brute force. To do better you need to do some real lexical analysis and simple parsing.

(Maybe this is obvious, but you could also test your function in the toplevel (the OCaml read-eval-print loop). The toplevel will handle the work of making a list from what you type in.)

Answer (score 0):

As Sys.argv is a `string array`, you need to write your own transcription function.

I guess the simplest way to do this is to use the [Genlex](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Genlex.html) module provided by the standard library.

```
let lexer = Genlex.make_lexer ["["; ";"; "]"; ]
let list_of_string s =
  let open Genlex in
  let open Stream in
  let stream = lexer (of_string s) in
  let fail () = failwith "Malformed string" in
  let rec aux acc =
    match next stream with
    | Int i ->
      ( match next stream with
        | Kwd ";" -> aux (i::acc)
        | Kwd "]" -> i::acc
        | _ -> fail () )
    | Kwd "]" -> acc
    | _ -> fail ()
  in
  try
    match next stream with
    | Kwd "[" -> List.rev (aux [])
    | _ -> fail ()
  with Stream.Failure -> fail ()

let list1 = list_of_string Sys.argv.(1)
let list2 = list_of_string Sys.argv.(2)
```

Depending on the OCaml flavor you want to use, some other library may look more interesting. If you like yacc, [Menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/) may solve your problem in a few lines of code.