# reading integers from a string

Tags: string, ocaml

I want to read a line from a file, initialize an array from that line and then display the integers. 
Why is is not reading the five integers in the line? I want to get output `1 2 3 4 5`, i have `1 1 1 1 1`

```
open Array;;
open Scanf;;

let print_ints file_name = 
  let file = open_in file_name in
  let s = input_line(file) in
  let n = ref 5 in
  let arr = Array.init !n (fun i -> if i < !n then sscanf s "%d" (fun a -> a) else 0) in
  let i = ref 0 in 
  while !i < !n do
    print_int (Array.get arr !i);
    print_string " ";
    i := !i + 1;
  done;;

print_ints "string_ints.txt";;
```

My file is just: `1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: Why is is not reading the five integers in the line? I want to get output 1 2 3 4 5, i have 11111

Comment: It's this part `sscanf s "%d" (fun a -> a)`: you always scan the same string `s` from the very beginning. `sscanf` doesn't change your string.

Comment: What can i do then to get all the integers from the string? There is int_of_string but that would try to convert the whole string to a numer. There is also get but that would only give me char not integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try the following approach. Split your string into a list of substrings representing numbers. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28082602/2747511) describes one way of doing so. Then use the resulting function in your `print_ints` function.

```
let ints_of_string s = 
  List.map int_of_string (Str.split (Str.regexp " +") s)

let print_ints file_name = 
  let file = open_in file_name in
  let s = input_line file in
  let ints = ints_of_string s in
  List.iter (fun i -> print_int i; print_char ' ') ints;
  close_in file

let _ = print_ints "string_ints.txt"
```

When compiling, pass `str.cma` or `str.cmxa` as an argument (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3221105/2747511) for details on compilation):

```
$ ocamlc str.cma print_ints.ml
```

Another alternative would be using the `Scanf.bscanf` function -- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746442/function-returns-list-in-reverse-order-in-ocaml), contains an example (use with caution).

The `Scanf.sscanf` function may not be particularly suitable for this task.
An excerpt from the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html):

> the scanf facility is not intended for heavy duty lexical analysis and parsing. If it appears not expressive enough for your needs, several alternative exists: regular expressions (module Str), stream parsers, ocamllex-generated lexers, ocamlyacc-generated parsers

There is though a way to parse a string of ints using `Scanf.sscanf` (which I wouldn't recommend):

```
let rec int_list_of_string s =
  try
    Scanf.sscanf s 
                 "%d %[0-9-+ ]" 
                 (fun n rest_str -> n :: int_list_of_string rest_str)
  with
    | End_of_file | Scanf.Scan_failure _ -> []
```

The trick here is to represent the input string `s` as a part which is going to be parsed into a an integer (`%d`) and the rest of the string using the range format: `%[0-9-+ ]"`, which will match the rest of the string, containing only decimal digits `0-9`, the `-` and `+` signs, and whitespace .

Comment: That solves the problem. Ocaml is very powerful with things like map but for scanning seems limited  having to use external things. Using sscanf could i do it ? It seems like i would always have to know how many ints for format.

Comment: `Str` is a standard module (not external), it's just compilation is a bit more complex. Yes, you have to fix your format string (I've updated the answer to reflect that).

Comment: You might enjoy this [tutorial on streams](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/streams.html). You can use streams here `let int_stream_of_string s =
  Stream.of_list (List.map int_of_string (Str.split (Str.regexp " +") s))` to process your strings in a piece-by-piece manner.

Comment: Your split won't handle negative numbers.

Comment: @vanmarcke I've added an example with `sscanf`.

Comment: @Heyji Because it's *really* slow.