# function returns list in reverse order in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to read some numbers from a file, take them to a list and finally display them on the screen.
numbers.txt currently has `2 3 5 7 11` however as output i'am getting `11 7 5 3 2 - : unit = ()`

Why is this happening?

```
let rec int_list_from_sb sb n = 
match n with 
| 0 -> [];
| _ -> (bscanf sb " %d" (fun a -> a))::(int_list_from_sb sb (n - 1));;

let file_name = open_in "numbers.txt" in 
let sb = Scanning.from_channel file_name in 
let int_list = int_list_from_sb sb 5 in
List.iter (fun a -> print_int a) int_list;;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified in OCaml. So when you do `f x :: g y`, it is unspecified whether `f` or `g` gets called first. In your case the recursive call is invoked before the call to `bscanf`, which is why you get the results in the wrong order.

The general way to fix evaluation-order issues is to put the arguments to a function into local variables when the order of their side effects matters. So instead of `f x :: g y`, you'd do `let fx = f x in fx :: g y` if you want the effects of `f x` to happen before `g` is called.

However in your case you can just make use of `bscanf`'s continuation argument like this:

```
bscanf sb " %d" (fun a -> a :: int_list_from_sb sb (n - 1))
```

Comment: if it chooses the second function here, the recursive one, what happens to the integer that bscanf obtained?

Comment: @power_output What happens is that `int_list_from_sb 4` evaluates, reading 4 numbers from `sb` and returning `[7; 5; 3; 2]`, then `bscanf sb " %d" (fun a -> a)` evaluates and returns `11` and then `11 :: [7; 5; 3; 2]` is evaluated and returns `[11; 7; 5; 3; 2]`.

Comment: @power_output You got lucky, because the system just deferred scanning in a predictable manner. The results could (*in principle*) be even more interesting, since `sb` is a mutable structure: imagine what would happen if both expressions were evaluated, for example, in turn.