# OCaml creating a list of ints from string

Tags: ocaml

I want to read a line with this structure:

```
7 12 129224 2 124 12 2 51
```

And put the elements of the string in a int list like the following:

```
[7; 12; 129224; 2; 124; 12; 2; 51]
```

The numbers could have any size and negative numbers are not to be considered. Here is what I have so far:

```
let size_s = read_int();; (* size_s is the number of elements within the String. In this case it's 8. *)
let s = read_line();;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the initial 8 that you're reading. It doesn't show up in your example.

However, this old answer shows one way to convert a string to a list of ints: [How to convert a string to integer list in ocaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082450/how-to-convert-a-string-to-integer-list-in-ocaml/28082602?s=2%7C0.3839#28082602).

Here's an example for many sizes of int:

```
List.map int_of_string (Str.split (Str.regexp "[^0-9]+") "123 8 67 4");;
- : int list = [123; 8; 67; 4]
```

Comment: I included the size_t because it could be used on someones solution. As for the link you provided me with, i've seen it but I think it only helps me convert one size ints like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 and not variable sizes int ,231. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: This is not correct. The code works for any non-negative ints at all.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but i've only managed to made it work on top-level, how should i proceed to compile and run the program? open Str? should i include any commands on linux terminal like str.cma? Thanks

Comment: This is a separate question. The short answer for linux is `ocamlc -o myfile str.cma myfile.ml`. You don't need to open `Str`, that's just for shorter naming. The code already uses the module name.